# Delete row according to a specific values in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I want to to delete rows in the `Conf_mat_Modis_2000` table if values in the column `Driver_90_00_Visual` either equal 0 or NA. Can someone help me out with that.

```
dput(Conf_mat_Modis_2000)
structure(list(Driver_90_00_Modis500 = c(100, 200, 200, 100, 
100, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 500, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 500, 500, 100, 200, 200, 100, 500, 100, 100, 500, 100, 
100, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 
100, 300, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 
200, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 100, 200, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
200, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 
200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 500, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 500, 100, 100, 
500, 100, 500, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 500, 
500, 100, 200, 100, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
200, 200, 200, 100, 500, 500, 500, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 200, 
100, 200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 500, 100, 100, 200, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 500, 500, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 100, 200, 200, 500, 
200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 500, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 
200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 
100, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 200, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 500, 100, 100, 100, 500, 100, 200, 
100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 500, 100, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 
100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 100, 
200, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 
200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 
200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 500, 200, 100, 100, 100, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 500), Driver_90_00_Visual = c(600, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, NA, 200, NA, 200, 200, 200, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 200, 200, 300, 200, 200, NA, 300, 200, 200, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 
500, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200, 200, NA, 200, 200, NA, NA, 200, 
NA, NA, NA, 200, NA, 200, 500, NA, 200, 200, NA, 500, NA, 200, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200, 200, 500, NA, NA, 200, NA, NA, NA, 
200, NA, NA, 200, 200, 200, NA, NA, NA, 200, NA, 200, 200, NA, 
200, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200, 200, 200, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200, 
NA, NA, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200, 
200, NA, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200, 500, NA, 500, 200, 500, NA, 
NA, NA, 200, NA, 500, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, 200, 500, NA, 
NA, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, 500, 
200, 200, 200, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 200, 200, NA, NA, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, NA, 500, 500, NA, 
NA, NA, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, 500, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 500, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, NA, 200, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 500, NA, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, NA, NA, 600, 600, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
500, 500, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, NA, NA, NA, 500, 500, NA, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 600, 500, 500, 500, 200, 200, 200, NA, 200, NA, 500, 500, 
200, 200, 200, 200, NA, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, NA, 999, 999, NA, 500, 999, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 500, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 
200, 500, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 500, NA, 500, 200, 200, 200, 
500, 500, 500, 200, 500, 500, 200, 500, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 
200, 500, 200, 200, NA, NA, NA, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 
500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 
200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 500, 200, 500, 200, 200, 500, 200, 500, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, NA, 200, NA, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, NA, NA, 
200, 200, 200, 500, 200, 500, 200, 500, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 
500, 200, 500, 200, 500, 500, 500, NA, 500, 200, 500, NA, 500, 
500, 200, 200, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 500, 200, 500, 200, 
NA, 500)), .Names = c("Driver_90_00_Modis500", "Driver_90_00_Visual"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1081L))
```

Comment: Based on your description, try: `Conf_mat_Modis_2000 <- Conf_mat_Modis_2000[Conf_mat_Modis_2000$Driver_90_00_Visual != 0 & !is.na(Conf_mat_Modis_2000$Driver_90_00_Visual),]`. And note that it's good to post a reproducible example, but those should be _minimized_.

Comment: @beginneR, with `Conf_mat_Modis_2000$Driver_90_00_Visual` instead of just `Driver_90_00_Visual`...

Comment: Maybe start going through an R tutorial to learn more about subsetting if you haven't done that yet. It's quite essential

Comment: The best practice before posting a question is to use Google first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume df is your data frame, could do

```
df[!(df$Driver_90_00_Visual %in% c(0, NA)),]
```

With reference to the comments:

```
df_is_na <- df[df$Driver_90_00_Visual != 0 & !is.na(df$Driver_90_00_Visual),]
df_NA <- df[!(df$Driver_90_00_Visual %in% c(0, NA)),]
identical(df_is_na, df_NA)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: NA is usually tested for with `is.na()` instead of `... == NA`

Comment: It works using the OP's dataset.

Comment: I'm just saying that it's perhaps not considered "good practice" (even though it might work here)

Comment: Check section 8.1.4 of http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf